# Flexslider really messing up my webpage in Chrome

Tags: jquery, flexslider, google-font-api

has anyone else had this kind of issue? I've got a drop down menu at the top of my page, then flexslider, then some general text and images...there are two fonts, one called from the Google fonts API and one using fontFace (just in case this is relevant!)..

When viewing in Chrome on my mac I get some very odd behavior. All the text on the page gets very "thin" each time the slides move, and some (but not all) navigation link "jump" up and right by a pixel. I've seen nothing like this and can only assume it's some weird conflict?? I've tested in everything I can find, FF, Opera, Safari and Chrome on the mac, IE9, Chrome on Windows and FF on Windows. Both versions of Chrome do not look good, but the mac one is much worse.

Unfortunately I'd rather not list my project on the web until it's 100% complete, and I think it's way too much stuff to make a fiddle..but after looking on the actual flexslider web page I found the same kind of fault, if you watch the thumbnails you'll see what I mean (if you're in Chrome of course). - http://flexslider.woothemes.com/thumbnail-controlnav.html

Does anyone know a fix because I'd like to keep the code I've been working on!

Comment: Chrome 22.0.1229.94 win7, Chromium 23.0.1255.0 (154635) linux, MSIE9 win7 - sample page looks the same. Maybe you could post the screenshot.

Comment: Hi nrodic - it would be hard to capture because it happens for about a second and it reverts to the previous (correct) state...

Comment: I'm not seeing any issues on Chrome 22.0.1229.94 (Mac).

Comment: This seems very changeable. It works ok on my iPad 2 in portrait, but in landscape it effects the navigation text, making it thinner when the slide moves. It's very strange!!

Answer (score 17):

Found a fix that seems to resolve the problem in Chrome without touching the JS:

The **-webkit-backface-visibility** combined with **useCSS:true** in the slider init causes fixed positioning and z-indexing to break under Chrome. I realized the weirdness was happening when I started playing around with the fixed top navbar, the slider container and z-index values -- setting the z-index higher than the fixed navbar made the odd text blinks go away but of course the slider then scrolled on top of the fixed navbar.

To work around this, do the following two things:

- In "flexslider.css" line 25:
  **.flexslider .slides > li**
  *Comment out* or *remove* **-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;**
- In the flexslider initialization script:
  *Specify* '**useCSS : false**' in your slider options*

*This is set to true as a default by the flexslider JS and tells the browser to use CSS3 3D transforms if they're available. An unnecessary feature if you ask me, and flexslider seems to work just fine without it.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, this is very interesting. I'm pretty full on with work but I want to get back to this very soon as my next job is going to need a responsive slider too!

Comment: All I had to do was specify useCSS: false, and it fixed the issue for me.  Thanks! Chrome 24.0.1312.56

Comment: Likewise - using 'useCSS : false' is all I needed as well.

Answer (score 17):

Apply -webkit-transform: translateZ(0); to the container of the affected element and this will halt the flickring.

This also works when you have an element within the flexslider that contains text.

CSS transforms still cause some strange behavior. Forcing the element to render as 3D seems to solve for graphic and performance glitches.

Tested on Chrome v27.0.1453.93.

Comment: This is the only Correct Answer.  I swear I thought I was going crazy.  The labels on a form were  flickering and applying -webkit-transform: translateZ(0); to the <form> tag fixed the problem.   Thank you so much.

Comment: This is very interesting. I've been doing more work with CSS3 animation techniques lately, and will try this. I've viewed several websites now where some of the content "jumps" a pixel or two when a single element is animating. Safari doesn't seem to do this for me...

Comment: I had an issue that drop down menus appeared then faded out *until* the next slider animation. Chrome only. Didn't seem to be a z-index issue. I applied this to the menu ul which fixed that. Voodoo!

Comment: Also, newer versions of flexslider.css don't appear to have the -webkit-backface-visibility as stated in another answer.

Comment: What a ball-ache. Just spent several hours trying debugging this and searching for the solution

Comment: I made my own theme with a fixed navbar, worked perfect except on pages that loaded jquery - if jquery was loaded on the page then the fixed navbar would jump a little bit as you scrolled up/down the page. This seems to have fixed it.

Answer (score 5):

Add position:relative & z-index:1 to .flex-viewport in css file

Comment: Totally worked for me... at least this fixes messed up (rotated) graphics (while the -webkit-backface-visibility approach did not).

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but I thought I'd just quickly post my solution after fiddling around for an hour.

As above:

- In "flexslider.css" line 25: .flexslider .slides > li Comment out or
  remove -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
- In the flexslider initialization script: Specify 'useCSS : false' in your slider option
- -webkit-transform: translateZ(0) on the parent element

Then add this to the bottom of "flexslider.css":

```
.flex-viewport {

    -webkit-transition: none;
    -moz-transition: none;
    transition: none;
}
```

That did it for me on Chrome! Hope it helps anyone else having this problem.

Comment: That's pretty much the same as setting the UseCSS argument to false. A lot off CSS3 issues are solved using the backface-visibilty property.

Answer (score 0):

I'm experiencing the exact same issue, having just implemented FlexSlider today into a Bootstrap responsive site. The problem doesn't replicate on Firefox or Safari (haven't checked IE yet and don't particularly want to).

I strongly suspect the problem lies with the various touch, keypress and other methods the FlexSlider JS implements to advance the slideshow, because I removed my CSS (including my href to the Google Font API) and JS scripts one by one to determine that FlexSlider's JS appears to be the culprit. The good news is, it's not a conflict with the Bootstrap responsive JS, nor does it seem to be any other CSS styles. Still troubleshooting though, sorry I can't be more helpful but at least it's not just you.

I'm going to post this on the FlexSlider forum. Maybe the developer will address a fix to this Chrome bug in the next release.

---

Chrome v23.0.1271.64

Answer (score 0):

In "flexslider.css" find ".flexslider .slides > li" Comment out or remove -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;

Answer (score 0):

The solution that gruntPi9 suggested worked for me. I had a problem in Chrome, images were jumping out of the frame, and his solution solved the problem.

Slider: FlexSlider 2

Browser: Chrome

Problem: Images jumping out of a frame

Solution:

- In "flexslider.css" line 25: .flexslider .slides > li comment out or remove -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
- In "jquery.flexslider.js": Specify 'useCSS : false' in your slider options

Comment: The `useCSS : false` option fixed the issues I had with jumpy elements. A lot of elements on my page seemed to shift 1 pixel each time the slide animation started or ended.